# Eclipse Task List View Keeps Losing Files

Tags: eclipse, task

I was really thrilled to discover Eclipse's Task List feature which is perfect for keeping tracks of files associated with a particular task and allowing me to switch back and forth between them instantly.

HOWEVER, I am noticing that while I am using this , switching between tasks, files , and creating new files, that some files I had open for a task just disappear from the tab bar!

This is not a very useful feature if I have to keep hunting down files I have in a task and keep opening them for that task. Once I open them I expect them to stay open in that task.

Am I missing something here or is this a bug? Using Kepler Release 2.

Comment: Have you tried it with Mars?

Comment: No sorry I don't have Mars installed.